# Finding the largest mirror image of integers present in an array of integers [CodingBat riddle: MaxMirror]

Tags: java, arrays

I am tryong to solve the problem [MaxMirror](http://codingbat.com/prob/p196409) on CodingBat:

> We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in {1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1} is length 3 (the {1, 2, 3} part). Return the size of the largest mirror section found in the given array.
>
> **maxMirror({1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1}) → 3**
>
> **maxMirror({1, 2, 1, 4}) → 3**
>
> **maxMirror({7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1}) → 2**

---

**Conditions for solving:**

1. No other helper methods.
2. Do not use Java.util.Arrays.copyOf or any other utility under Arrays
3. Do not use collections.

The solution I got works for all the cases except {7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7} it should return 5 but I got 6. What am I doing wrong here?

Though at CodingBat it shows All Correct on running, does it also show that CodingBat doesn't check against all possible scenarios?

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  final int len=nums.length;
  if(len==0)
  return 0;
  int maxCount=1;
  boolean flag=false;

  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
     int tempCount=1;
     int count=i;

     for(int j=len-1;j>=0&&(count<len);j--)
     {
        if((nums[count]==nums[j])&&!(flag))
        {
          flag=true;
          count++;
          continue;
        }
        if((nums[count]==nums[j])&&(flag))
        {
          tempCount++;
          count++;
          maxCount=(tempCount>maxCount)?tempCount:maxCount;
         continue;
        }
        if(!(nums[i]==nums[j])&&(flag))
        {
          flag=false;
          count=i;
          tempCount=1;
          continue;
        }
        if((j==count)||(j-count)==1)
        {
          flag=false;
          break;
          }

      }
  }    
      return maxCount;    

}
```

Comment: you will get more explanation on the website forum..in these sites usually there are test cases which are already fixed and the o/p is checked against it..there can be a chance that these type of test cases were not on the sites..there are also randomly generated input against which answer is checked..so it might be possible that these type of test cases were not generated by the system..

Comment: I could report this to the guy who created codingBat would only be helpful for someone in future.

Comment: yeah..of course..you can always tell these things to them..they will  fix it and will try to maximize `corner test cases` in other questions also

Comment: Any suggestions of what's going wrong here?

Comment: you have already asked this question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55145/finding-the-largest-mirror-image-of-a-subset-of-integers-present-in-an-array-of here..i think you might have got your answer there

Comment: No..this question is unanswered...I asked for a review and then came across this corner case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix made the flag was not being set to false in the outer loop the fix is not visible  [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55145/finding-the-largest-mirror-image-of-a-subset-set-of-integers-present-in-an-array?noredirect=1#comment96954_55145)

Answer (score 0):

```
` public int maxMirror(int[] arr){
        int i,j,temp,max,count;
        i=j=temp=max=count=0;
        while(i < arr.length-1){
            count=0;
            temp=i;
            j=arr.length-1;
            while(j >= temp){
                if(arr[temp] == arr[j]){
                     count++;
                     if(temp==j) count++;
                     temp++;
                }
                else if(count > 0) break;                
                if(max < count) max=count;
                j--;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return max;
 }`
```

Comment: maxMirror([1]) should be 1, got 0.  maxMirror([1, 2, 3, 2, 1]) should be 5, got 4. 
maxMirror([5, 9, 9, 4, 5, 4, 9, 9, 2]) should be 7, got 5.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me try out!

```
static int count=0;

     public static void main(String []args){


       int max=0;//char that hold max of the count
       int[] a= new int[]{1,2,3,4,3,2,1};//input
       int length=a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<=length-1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<=length-1;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]==a[j])//comparing each number with everother to find a match
                {

                    for(int k=i,l=j;k<=l;k++,l--)
                    //to find the length of the mirror
                    {
                        if(a[k]==a[l])
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                        else{
                            break;//break if the mirror ends
                        }

                    }
                    if(count>max)
                        {
                            max=count;//updating max with the maximum of count

                        }
                        count=0;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the value of max mirror"+max);//value of max mirror
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code works too, check it out! Just pass it any int[] and it will return a int that is the value of the biggest mirror in the array.

```
    public static int maxMirror(int[] myArray) {
    
        int mirrorToReturn = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            int walkingIndex = i;
            int currentMirror = 0;
            for (int j = myArray.length - 1; j >= walkingIndex; j--) {
                if (myArray[walkingIndex] == myArray[j]) {
                    if (walkingIndex == j) {
                        currentMirror += 1;
                    } 
                    else {
                        currentMirror += 1; // counts pairs as 1
                    }
                    walkingIndex++;
                } 
                else if (myArray[walkingIndex] != myArray[j]) {
                    walkingIndex = i;
                    currentMirror = 0;
                }
                if (currentMirror > mirrorToReturn) {
                    mirrorToReturn = currentMirror;
                }
            }
        }
        return mirrorToReturn; 
    }
```

Note, my code counts each pair as 1, but you can change it to 2. I put a comment next to the code, so you can easily locate it and change it if needed.

Answer (score -4):

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
 int count=0;
 int MAX=0;
  for(int i=0 ; i<nums.length ; i++)
      for(int j=nums.length-1; j>=0; j--)
         { 
          if(nums[i]==nums[j])
              { count=0;
                  for(int k=0 ; k<nums.length-i ; k++)
                  if((i+k<nums.length)&&(j-k>=0)&&(nums[i+k]==nums[j-k]))
                    count=count+1;
                   else break;
              }
            MAX=Math.max(MAX,count);  
          }

         return MAX;
}
```